# trying to use flickity when screen resizes

Tags: jquery, html, css

the following jquery code is the one I am using to apply flickity slider for my divs when the screen size reduces! but this isn't working... please tell me what wrong with this code:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).resize(function resize(){
        if ($window.width() < 700) {
            $(".container").addClass('gallery').addClass('js-flickity');
            $(".article").addClass('gallery-cell');
        }

        $(".container").removeClass('gallery').removeClass('js-flickity');
        $(".article").removeClass('gallery-cell');
    }).trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

Here, container is the class that wraps the divs(class:article). following is the css for gallery and gallery-cell:

```
.gallery {
    background: #EEE;
}

.gallery-cell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #8C8;
    counter-increment: gallery-cell;
}

/* cell number */
.gallery-cell:before {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    content: counter(gallery-cell);
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;
}
```

Please let me know the problem with code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check this out you should use default Flickity options.

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/xVBpqG

// enable prev/next buttons at 768px

```
if ( matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 768px)').matches ) {
  options.prevNextButtons = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your code it goes like this:

if window.width < 700 add some classes
then remove the classes you probably just added

your code always removes the classes!
:D